# Jison rule precedence

Tags: grammar, bison, jison

I'm trying to create a grammar for a programming language in Jison, and have run into a problem with calls. Functions in my language is invoked with the following syntax:

```
functionName arg1 arg2 arg3
```

In order to do arguments that aren't just simple expressions, they need to be wrapped in parenthesizes like this:

```
functionName (1 + 2) (3 + 3) (otherFunction 5)
```

However, there is a bug in my grammar that causes my parser to interpret `functionName arg1 arg2 arg3` as `functionName(arg1(arg2(arg3)))` instead of `functionName(arg1, arg2, arg3)`.

The relevant part of my jison grammar file looks like this:

```
expr:
  | constantExpr         { $$ = $1; }
  | binaryExpr           { $$ = $1; }
  | callExpr             { $$ = $1; }
  | tupleExpr            { $$ = $1; }
  | parenExpr            { $$ = $1; }
  | identExpr            { $$ = $1; }
  | blockExpr            { $$ = $1; }
  ;

callArgs:
  | callArgs expr { $$ = $1.concat($2); }
  | expr                     { $$ = [$1]; }
  ;

callExpr:
  | path callArgs { $$ = ast.Expr.Call($1, $2); }
  ;

identExpr:
  | path                 { $$ = ast.Expr.Ident($1); }
  ;
```

How can I make Jison prefer the `callArgs` rather than the `expr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this by playing games with precedence relations, but I think the most straightforward solution is to be clear.

What you want to say is that `callArgs` cannot directly contain a `callExpr`. As in your example, if you want to pass a `callExpr` as an argument, you need to enclose it in parentheses, in which case it will match some other production (presumably `parenExpr`).

So you can write that directly:

```
callArgExpr
  : constantExpr
  | binaryExpr
  | tupleExpr
  | parenExpr
  | identExpr
  | blockExpr
  ;

expr
  : callArgExpr
  | callExpr
  ;

callArgs
  : callArgs callArgExpr   { $$ = $1.concat($2); }
  | callArgExpr            { $$ = [$1]; }
  ;

callExpr
  : path callArgs          { $$ = ast.Expr.Call($1, $2); }
  ;
```

In fact, it's likely that you want to restrict `callArgs` even further, since (if I understand correctly) `func a + b` does not mean "apply `a+b` to `func`", which would have been written `func (a + b)`. So you might want to also remove `binaryExpr` from `callArgExpr`, and possibly some other. I hope the model above shows how to do that.

By the way, I removed all the empty productions, assuming that they were unintentional (unless `jison` has some exception for that syntax; I'm not really a `jison` expert). And I removed `{ $$ = $1; }`, which I believe is as unnecessary in `jison` as in the classic yacc/bison/etc., since it is the default action.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. This turned out to be the way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

It is important to review other parts of your grammar to give a precise answer. I do not know if what I think is right, but from what I saw in your code, you could create a rule explicitly for the arguments in the order that you want without nesting one inside the other:

```
args:
    |    "(" simple_expression ")" args { /*Do something with $2*/ }
    |    "\n"
    ;
```

I hope this has helped you a little. Greetings.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I do not want to wrap arguments in parenthesizes. Only compound arguments. `a b c d` in my grammar should mean `a(b, c, d)` in traditional C like languages.